# comparing colours ignoring alpha component

Tags: c#, .net

I have a situation where I want to take a `Bitmap` and go through it replacing given colours with different colours. My original plan was to pass in a `Dictionary<Color, Color>` and then loop through all pixels checking if the current color is in the dictionary/map and then replace if needed.

However, if the original image has any alpha I want to retain that alpha. I'm puzzling over the best way to check if a colour is in the dictionary ignoring the alpha component.

The way I've come up with so far is just to create a new `RGBOnlyColor` class or similar and use that instead of `Color` in my dictionary and convert the color I get from `GetPixel` to this before looking it up. This seems quite overkill though so I was wondering if there is anything I have missed to make it simpler...

The other option is to create a ColorMap class which would be a simple extension of dictionary which when setting and retrieving just forces the alpha to a known value to ensure that it is irrelevant...

So can anybody help me with what the best way to do this is? In summary I want to swap colours in an image leaving the alpha part intact but it is harder than it seems it should be... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward approach would be to zero out the alpha channel of each color before looking it up in the dictionary, then injecting the correct alpha value after the mapped color is resolved.

Example:

```
Color colorFromBitmap; // assume already have this
var colorToLookup = Color.FromArgb(0, colorFromBitmap);
var mappedColor = dictionary[colorToLookup];
var finalResult = Color.FromArgb(colorFromBitmap.A, mappedColor);
```

Since the alpha is set to `0` before colors are looked up in the dictionary, the colors inside the dictionary should all have a `0` alpha as well.

Comment: D'oh! Of course its as simple as that. It didn't even occur to me to modify the colour I was getting from the image before testing it against the dictionary. :)

Answer (score 2):

To compare the colours, excluding comparison of alpha, you don't need any more than this:

```
bool RGBequal(Color c1, Color c2)
{
    return c1.R==c2.R && c1.G==c2.G && c1.B==c2.B;
}
```

To implement your dictionary based approach you could populate the dictionary with colours that have alpha value of 255 using `Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)`. Perhaps use an extension method:

```
Color Opaque(this Color color)
{
    return Color.FromArgb(color.R, color.G, color.B);
}
```

Creating a new color that combines the alpha channel from one color with the RGB from another color is simple enough:

```
Color.FromArgb(color1.A, color2.R, color2.G, color2.B);
```